# ESP8266 with 1C5V Relay - always ON

Tags: arduino, relay, esp8266, low-power

Please find the circuit:

[image]

I am using [NodeMCU ESP8266](https://robocraze.com/products/nodemcu-esp8266-amica-cp2102-driver) and [1C 5V Relay](https://robocraze.com/products/1-ch-5v-relay-board). ESP8266 board is connected to the USB port of laptop and it is powering the board. The problem is, whenever I upload the code to the ESP8266 board, the relay will be always ON.

Here's the relevant portion of code that am using in Arduino IDE:

```
define RELAY_PIN D1;

void setup(){
    Serial.beign(115200);
    pinMode(RELAY_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);
}
```

The problem is, whenever I upload the code to ESP8266, the green light keeps ON (along with red LED) eventhough in code I have set it to LOW.

I tried changing the input pin of relay to other digital pin ports in the ESP8266 board. Same issue. During upload, the ESP8266 resets. And at that time, only the red LED is lighted while the green is off.

I tried debugging and found that, no matter I tried passing LOW or HIGH through the `digitalWrite()` for that pin, it's always GREEN.

When debugged the code, I found that it is after this line `pinMode(RELAY_PIN, OUTPUT);`, the green led is running ON always.

I tried connecting the Vcc of the Relay to the board's 3v pin (instead of the Vin), as I saw this as a solution while googling, but still same issue.

Comment: Your relay is active LOW, so `digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW)` actually turn on the relay. To turn it off, there are [similar case](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/556804/5-v-relay-connected-to-arduino?rq=1) for ESP8266 unable to turn it off with `digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH)`, to turn it off, you can try to change the pin to `pinMode(RELAY_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP)` to see if it is work?

Comment: @hcheung thanks. That worked!